# How to create a list of spinners?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-spinner

I have a list that dynamically grows with the push of a button. Inside each list item I would like to have spinners (drop down menu's). I have already created the dynamic list (code below) but am not sure how to make a list of spinners. Also, how would I retrieve the selected data from all the spinners?

```
this.listItems = new ArrayList<String>();

this.listViewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        getActivity(),
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        this.listItems
);


ListView listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);
listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);

this.addToList = v.findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
this.addToList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        listItems.add("hi");
        listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});

this.deleteFromList = v.findViewById(R.id.delBtn);
this.deleteFromList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int index = listItems.size() - 1;
        if(index >= 0) {
            listItems.remove(index);
            listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
});
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addBtn"
        android:text="Add New Order"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="addItems"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/delBtn"
        android:text="Delete Order"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="delItem"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" >
    </ListView>
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/test_spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/test_array" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submitBtn"
        android:text="Submit Order"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="submitOrder" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Ideally I would like each list item to be a spinner.

Answer (score 1):

Make an arraylist with all spinner and when you need to get data make loop on it